# Firefox shows gap between main and dropdown menu with increased line height

Tags: html, css, firefox, drop-down-menu, flexbox

[In this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akas30a8/) I do have a menu which displays dropdown menus for some items. The main menu and the submenu items do have an increased height. I am using the line-height property for this purpose.

```css
/* body ---------------------------------------------------------- */

body {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
}


/* header ---------------------------------------------------------- */

header {
  width: 100%;
}

.header-div {
  width: 920px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}


/* main-menu ---------------------------------------------------------- */

div.float-left-menu {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

ul#main-menu {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  text-align: center;
}

ul#main-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 200%;
  list-style: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 120px;
}

ul#main-menu li:hover {
  background-color: #4f569d;
}

ul#main-menu li a {
  background: none;
  color: #4f569d;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul#main-menu li span {
  background: none;
  color: #4f569d;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul#main-menu li:hover>a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul#main-menu li:hover>span {
  color: #fff;
}

ul#main-menu li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  /*top: 138%; hack for FF, otherwise there is a gap between the main menu and the dropdown menu*/
}


/* header-submenu ---------------------------------------------------------- */

ul#header-submenu {
  display: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 1;
}

ul#header-submenu li {
  display: block;
  line-height: 200%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  background-color: #bbb;
  list-style: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 240px;
}

ul#header-submenu li:hover {
  background-color: #4f569d;
}

ul #header-submenu li a {
  background: none;
  color: #4f569d;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul#header-submenu li:hover>a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header-div">
    <div class="float-left-menu">
      <nav>
        <ul id="main-menu">
          <li><a href="~/">Item 1</a></li>
          <li>
            <span>Sub 1</span>
            <ul id="header-submenu">
              <li><a href="#">SItem 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">SItem 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span>Sub 2</span>
            <ul id="header-submenu">
              <li><a href="#">SItem 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">SItem 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

While the dropdown menu is displayed seemlessly below its parent item in Chrome, IE and Edge, Firefox displays a gap, which not only looks unfavourable but also makes the dropdown go away when the mouse cursor is moved there for selection. The problem does not appear with 'normal' height.
For `line-height: 200%;` I was able to fix the problem by adding `top: 138%;` to the `ul` of the dropdown, but frankly this approach is too much try-and-error.
Is there a cleaner solution for Firefox?

Comment: Don’t use line-height, but a padding-top/-bottom instead …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `position` to get the same

Update css part

```
    ul#main-menu li {
        display: inline-block;
        line-height: 200%;
        list-style: none;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 120px;
        position:relative; /*add this*/
    }

    ul#header-submenu {
        display: none;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: left;
        z-index: 1;
        position:absolute; /*add this*/
        top:auto; /*add this you can change as your need */
        left:0px; /*add this you can change as your need */
}
```

```css
/* body ---------------------------------------------------------- */

body {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  /* put the top margin into the header, otherwise there will always be a vertical scrollbar */
}


/* header ---------------------------------------------------------- */

header {
  width: 100%;
}

.header-div {
  width: 920px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}


/* main-menu ---------------------------------------------------------- */

div.float-left-menu {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

ul#main-menu {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  text-align: center;
}

ul#main-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 200%;
  list-style: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 120px;
  position: relative;
}

ul#main-menu li:hover {
  background-color: #4f569d;
}

ul#main-menu li a {
  background: none;
  color: #4f569d;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul#main-menu li span {
  background: none;
  color: #4f569d;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul#main-menu li:hover>a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul#main-menu li:hover>span {
  color: #fff;
}

ul#main-menu li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  /*top: 138%; hack for FF, otherwise there is a gap between the main menu and the dropdown menu*/
}


/* header-submenu ---------------------------------------------------------- */

ul#header-submenu {
  display: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  left: 0px;
}

ul#header-submenu li {
  display: block;
  line-height: 200%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  background-color: #eee;
  list-style: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 240px;
}

ul#header-submenu li:hover {
  background-color: #4f569d;
}

ul #header-submenu li a {
  background: none;
  color: #4f569d;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul#header-submenu li:hover>a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header-div">
      <div class="float-left-menu">
        <nav>
          <ul id="main-menu">
            <li><a href="~/">Item 1</a></li>
            <li>
              <span>Sub 1</span>
              <ul id="header-submenu">
                <li><a href="#">SItem 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SItem 2</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span>Sub 2</span>
              <ul id="header-submenu">
                <li><a href="#">SItem 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SItem 2</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Working fiddle also included

**[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/akas30a8/7/)**